# Populate dropdown with relation data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a relation of category and sub category, I'm getting category data with related sub category using this query:

```
$data=Category::with('subcategory')->find($categoryID);
```

now i' getting category with related sub categories, that sub categories array i want to populate in the dropdown, Is there any way so that i can populate sub categories data without looping.

```
 {{ Form::select('subcategory[]',$subcat,[],['class'=>'form-control','multiple'=>true]) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you will need fetch sub categories ids like so

```
$sub_categories = $data->subcategory()->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

now you will pass `$sub_categories` to your view and in your form select

```
{{ Form::select('subcategory[]',$sub_categories,[],['class'=>'form-control','multiple'=>true]) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried but it contains array of data:[{"id":3,"sub_cat_id":2,"s_id":1,"created_at":"2020-07-17 16:48:07"},{"id":4,"sub_cat_id":2,"s_id":2,"created_at":"2020-07-17 16:48:07"}], i want to pass sub_cat_id in the third parameter so to make that sub category checked